# Is it possible to look ahead in the keyboard input buffer and detect barcode entry in MFC/Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

We have a legacy application which uses a variety of individual key presses to perform certain functions. Now we want to add a barcode scanner, but if the input focus is not in the right place, that can lead to the barcode being interpreted as a set of individual commands, not a multi-character barcode.

My initial thought was to pause momentarily when the first char is available, then check how many chars are available in the input buffer, and treat the input as a barcode if there are multiple characters waiting. However, this doesn't work - `std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` always returns zero:

```
Sleep( 50 );
const char ch( std::cin.get() );
std::cin.putback( ch );
if ( std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() >= 6 )
{
    // code never reached :-(
}
```

The code above was inserted in the context of a `PreTranslateMessage()` override for a `WN_KEYDOWN` message. Could it be that the messages are not yet translated, and therefore `std::cin` has no access to the characters? If so, is it possible to determine how many `WM_KEYDOWN` messages are queued instead of how many characters? It's not obvious how to do that via the MFC and/or Win32 APIs.

Comment: Is your program a console or a GUI app?

Comment: Consider using the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/raw-input) to detect which physical device is sending input. You can differentiate between an actual keyboard and a barcode scanner that is pretending to be a keyboard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that would make a great answer if you fleshed it out. I wasn't even aware there was a way to detect which device was sending input.

Comment: Related: [How do I tell if keyboard input is coming from a barcode scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620745/): "*If you're using a barcode scanner, this gets a lot easier. Because they're explicitly designed for this purpose, they're almost all programmable. Meaning that you can tell them to prefix (and/or suffix) their input with some sentinel characters that indicate the input is coming from the barcode scanner, rather than a standard keyboard. ... Then, all you have to do is filter out the keyboard input based on the presence or absence of those sentinel characters.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a window program, if you don't call `AllocConsole`, has no `stdin/stdout/stderr`. And `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` will always fail. So this method is not applicable.

You can make barcode scanner add prefixes and suffixes (some characters that not the same as your keyboard) that indicate the input is coming from the barcode scanner, rather than a standard keyboard. You can easily set up this with manuals or APIs provided by barcode scanner supplier.

Other non-recommended solutions:

1. Judge the interval between `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.
2. Judge the interval between two keystrokes.
   If it's slower, it's keybord input, else barcode scanner. (Not suitable for sending command through code simulation keyboard input)